# xcode6 - Is there a way to display echo statements from the build script to the console?

Tags: build, console, xcode6, output, echo

I have echo statements in my build script.  I used to be able to see them in the console during the build.  Now I cannot figure out how to turn it on.  All other questions and information I have found on the Internet is for previous versions of Xcode and none of them work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the Report Navigator button and select the build log you want. I'll put an image here to show you as soon as I can.

Comment: OK, I found out how to that but I still want to see echo statements in the console during the build.  So, in the latest version of Xcode one cannot set echo statements in their build script and see the output in the console?